# Is there a way to get the project directory from the library is called?

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a library and I would like to know how can I get the directory where my user is calling my library.

I mean:

This is what I have inside my R library Tree

app.R

```
write(json_value, paste0(fileName, ".json"))
```

I want to write the `fileName` file in the directory where the user called my library(Tree).
At first I tried with this:

```
getwd()
```

But this functions gives me the place where my library is, and this not what I want. I want that my library recognize the place where the user is calling the library and then return the path directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `shinyAppDir` in your package to run the app? Something like:

```
runMyApp <- function(){
  shinyAppDir(......)
}
```

?

In this case you could do:

```
runMyApp <- function(){
  options(wd = getwd())
  shinyAppDir(......)
}
```

And in the Shiny app you can get the working directory by doing `getOption("wd")`:

```
wd <- getOption("wd")
write(json_value, file.path(wd, paste0(fileName, ".json")))
```

Comment: Yes! I am doing this inside my library  ```appDir <- system.file("myapp", package = "Tree")     shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")``` but in my app.R file I have this line ```write(json_value, paste0(fileName, ".json"))``` which help me to save a json file but I want to save this file in the directory where the user call my function

Comment: @coding I edited my answer. Is it clearer?